# Overwriting properties file during ant build

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, m2eclipse

am working on a java project where am using ant as build tool.

I have two .property files say build_local and build_env. When I build the project through ant it should use build_local properties file and when am building the project for environment it should overwrite the build_local and use build_env.

Thanks in advance for any help. It would be great if you could post some references.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this example where you can pass arguments to ant build file.
[How do I pass an argument to an Ant task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911536/how-do-i-pass-an-argument-to-an-ant-task)

So in your case for local build use

```
ant -Denv=build_local -f your_antfile.xml
```

For non local files call

```
 ant -Denv=build_env -f your_antfile.xml
```

Needless to say  in your_antfile.xml you need to refer the properties files as 
 "${env}.properties"